# Color Scale entire row based on one column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Suppose I want to color scale complete rows on the basis of values in a column (using Google Sheets inbuilt color scale option in the conditional formatting menu). How do I achieve this?

[image: Picture of my Spreadsheet]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score -4):

How to fix this, is to sect the entire row and if there is a section you don't want to color then don't include it in the range data. Full row: `4:4` off section: `D4:Z4`
If you are asking how to input the column values then use the formula `Vlookup("Range that it is based on","the ratio","2",if it is text then"false")`
The ratio means the if statements like `If A9 equals 7 then 9` in that case it would equal 9 or you could just color it.

here is a sheet for you to see it laid out
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_llXokb_WkmhBS8jQttZHHPG_lXJXJXsESnMnSRxzi0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The example sheet is in the trash, not very effective for an answer here. If I understand what the OP is asking (I went looking for this question because I have it as well) this does not answer the question, it makes the rows uncolored. The goal is to color scale based on a column (ie data in columns a-c doesn't skew what is considered the "range" of the scale but they are formatted based on the where column d is in the range)